# Value for the interfacial tension and surface energy of stainless steel

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, surface-tension

I measured in an experiment the contact angle of stainless steel with 3 different liquids (water, glycerol and ethylene glycol). Through a fit with the 'Equation of State' from Neumann I obtained an interfacial tension of $32 \pm 3 \frac{\mathrm{mN}}{\mathrm{m}}$. In the context of a contact angle measurement interfacial tension and surface tension can be used synonyms (right?). Next, I would like to compare my value to already existing data. But my research ended with the following problem:

The paper [Line Energy and the Relation between Advancing, Receding, and Young Contact Angles](https://doi.org/10.1021/la049410h) states

> The surface tension can also be viewed as surface energy (energy per unit area of the surface).

Okay fine. But in my research, I often found different values for surface tensions ($\approx 40 \frac{\mathrm{mN}}{\mathrm{m}}$) and surface energy (for metals which have high surface energy, between $500 \frac{\mathrm{mN}}{\mathrm{m}}$ to $5000 \frac{\mathrm{mN}}{\mathrm{m}}$).
So what do I oversee here? It seems that there is no clear labeling.

A few times surface free energy also was mentioned, maybe sometimes it was confused with surface energy. But from what I know surface energy and surface free energy are not the same in general.